# Summarizing by groups applying function which involves the next group

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, dplyr

Let's assume I have the following data:

```
set.seed(1)
test <- data.frame(letters=rep(c("A","B","C","D"),10), numbers=sample(1:50, 40, replace=TRUE))
```

I want to know how many numbers whose letter is `A` are not in `B`, how many numbers of `B` are not in `C` and so on.

I came up with a solution for this using base functions `split` and `mapply`:

```
s.test <-split(test, test$letters)
notIn <- mapply(function(x,y) sum(!s.test[[x]]$numbers %in% s.test[[y]]$numbers), x=names(s.test)[1:3], y=names(s.test)[2:4])
```

Which gives:

```
> notIn
A B C 
9 7 7
```

But I would also like to do this with `dplyr` or `data.table`. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't think this can be done elegantly using plyr. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20174829/1201032 and the discussion I had with Hadley (plyr's author) in the comments. So the only way will be somewhat inefficient: for each letter, you will have to subset the whole `test` data to find the next letter.

Comment: small improvement for your base code: `mapply(function(x,y) sum(!x$numbers %in% y$numbers), head(s.test, -1), tail(s.test, -1))`

Comment: Nice, I did not think of using head/tails, it looks more elegant indeed. But I was still hoping there was a `dplyr` or `data.table` solution, for my real dataset is really big, so speed would help (though I am not sure they would really be faster, I would have to test).

Comment: How many unique values do you have in column `letters` in your actual data? And how big is *really big*?

Comment: Right now I have around 200 groups and 5000 observations per group. But this is an ongoing analysis, the data gets bigger every day.

Comment: Probably starting next week the data will grow 150.000 observations per day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bottleneck seems to be in `split`. When simulated on 200 groups and 150,000 observations each, `split` takes 50 seconds out of the total 54 seconds.

The `split` step can be made drastically faster using `data.table` as follows.

```
## test is a data.table here
s.test <- test[, list(list(.SD)), by=letters]$V1
```

Here's a benchmark on data of your dimensions using `data.table` + `mapply`:

```
## generate data
set.seed(1L)
k = 200L
n = 150000L
test <- data.frame(letters=sample(paste0("id", 1:k), n*k, TRUE), 
                 numbers=sample(1e6, n*k, TRUE), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

require(data.table)   ## latest CRAN version is v1.9.2
setDT(test)           ## convert to data.table by reference (no copy)
system.time({
    s.test <- test[, list(list(.SD)), by=letters]$V1 ## split
    setattr(s.test, 'names', unique(test$letters))   ## setnames
    notIn <- mapply(function(x,y) 
         sum(!s.test[[x]]$numbers %in% s.test[[y]]$numbers), 
              x=names(s.test)[1:199], y=names(s.test)[2:200])
})

##   user  system elapsed 
##  4.840   1.643   6.624
```

That's about ~7.5x speedup on your biggest data dimensions. Would this be sufficient?

Comment: My first thought was that given what they want to do with the data, it might make more sense to store it in wide format, rather than long, or even just a plain list, since then you're just avoiding the splitting altogether, data.table or no. If they stored it that way up front, I wonder how fast a simple loop through the columns would be.

Comment: Yeap, +1, I tested on the real data.frame and this speed up was really substantial! @joran today the data is already collected in that form, maybe tranforming it to wide format could be helpful, but I am not sure (because I would have to do this a lot of times), I will give it a shot though.

Comment: Couldn't you also tackle this with a cross join?

Comment: @hadley, I don't see an obvious way. How do you mean to do it?

Comment: @arun my intuition is that you could do a self cross join, drop the cases where the rows are the same on both sides, and then `setdiff` the variables.

Comment: @hadley, not sure what a self cross join is. But `setdiff` won't be possible here as `setdiff(a,b)` will not retain duplicate values in `a` to then calculate the length on.

Comment: @arun Sorry, a self cartesian join - i.e. join the data table to itself with `CJ()`.  Didn't realised preservation of duplicates was important here.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to give about the same speedup as with data.table but only uses base R.  Instead of splitting the data frame it splits the numbers column only (in line marked ##):

```
## generate data - from Arun's post
set.seed(1L)
k = 200L
n = 150000L
test <- data.frame(letters=sample(paste0("id", 1:k), n*k, TRUE), 
                 numbers=sample(1e6, n*k, TRUE), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

system.time({
    s.numbers <- with(test, split(numbers, letters)) ##
    notIn <- mapply(function(x,y) 
         sum(!s.numbers[[x]] %in% s.numbers[[y]]), 
              x=names(s.numbers)[1:199], y=names(s.numbers)[2:200])
})
```