# filter two data frames by the same group variables in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

In many occasions, after grouping a data frame by some variables, I want to apply a function that uses data from another data frame that is grouped by the same variables. The best solution I found is to use *semi_join* inside the function as follow:

```
d1 <- data.frame(model = c(1,1,2,2), x = runif(4) )
d2 <- data.frame(model=c(1,1,1,2,2,2), y = runif(6) )

myfun <- function(df1, df2) {
   subsetdf2 <- semi_join(df2, df1)
   data.frame(z = sum(d1$x) - sum(subsetdf2$y)) # trivial manipulation just to exemplify
}

d1 %>% group_by(model) %>% do(myfun(., d2))
```

The problem is that *semi_join* returns 'Joining by...' messages and, as I am using the function to do bootstrap, I get many messages that collapse the console. So, is there any way to reduce the verbosity of joins? Do you know a more elegant way to do something like this?

P.S. I asked a similar question a few years ago for *plyr*: [subset inside a function by the variables specified in ddply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171053/subset-inside-a-function-by-the-variables-specified-in-ddply)

Comment: In your example, d2 is not grouped by any variable.

Comment: I view it as implicitly grouped inside the function with the semi_join function

Comment: If you want to get rid of the messages, be explicit about what variables you are joining.

Comment: Now, I am solving this kind of problem using map2 from package purrr.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is stop the 'Joining by: ' statement, you just need to specify what column you are joining on with the `by` argument.

For example:

```
semi_join(d2, d1, by="model")
```

EDIT - As an alternative to using `semi_join` you can use a `base` solution. As the `group_by` function is passing the data by groups, you can filter using a simple indexing statement.  This will avoid the need for an additional parameter.  **This also currently assumes that the column of interest is the first column.**

```
myfun <- function(df1, df2) {
  subsetdf2 <- df2[df2[,1] %in% unique(df1[,1]),]
  data.frame(z = sum(df1$x) - sum(subsetdf2$y)) # trivial manipulation just to exemplify
}
```

Comment: I would like not to use 'model' explicitly inside the function. I guess that I can use something like group_var='model', then something like d1 %>% group_by_(group_var) %>% do(myfun(., d2, group_var)) and finally inside the function use the group_bar in the join but it doesn't seem neat.

Comment: @danilinares, could you update your question to how you would like the final function structured?  You currently use model directly in your current solution so I didn't attempt to avoid it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand well your suggestion about changing the question. What I would not like is to introduce the grouping variables by hand inside 'myfun'. In the attempt that I suggested the dataframe df2 is filtered by the grouping variables of the do() without the need to explicitly indicate which are the grouping variables.

Comment: @danilinares, does my edit above address your problem sufficiently?

Comment: I am looking for something more general, but extending your first solution as I said in the follow-up comment is good enough for me at the moment (I posted it as a posible solution).

Answer (score 0):

I adapted the solution of @cdeterman. It is a bit redundant though.

```
d1 <- data.frame(model = c(1,1,2,2), x = runif(4) )
d2 <- data.frame(model=c(1,1,1,2,2,2), y = runif(6) )

myfun <- function(df1, df2, gv) {
  subsetdf2 <- semi_join(df2, df1, by = gv)
  data.frame(z = sum(d1$x) - sum(subsetdf2$y)) # trivial manipulation just to     exemplify
}

group_var <- 'model'
d1 %>% group_by_(group_var) %>% do(myfun(., d2,group_var))
```